# how to use list data in react native which is come from firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native

here is my data which is come from the firebase database

```
{
   "-McT4fSeXaMtZG2uitBJ":{
      "channelid":"55c9b29f-290d-4104-b598-5a8b735e5cc1",
      "comments":"cvvb",
      "name":"sirajul",
      "profilepic":"http://ghhgjjech.org/app-property/images/uploads/demo-profile.png"
   },
   "-McT5Tz2_9GnEjbbuyeH":{
      "channelid":"55c9b29f-290d-4104-b598-5a8b735e5cc1",
      "comments":"fthj",
      "name":"sirajul",
      "profilepic":"http://ghhgjjechotech.org/app-property/images/uploads/demo-profile.png"
   }
}
```

I use this to fetch firebase data

```
itemsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
            let data = snapshot.val();
            setCommentLists(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
```

now I want to list all the data. how to do that?

Comment: Did you tried `snapshot.forEach` and get each object from it and push to new array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript .map() Function. With that you can run threw your Array CommentLists and display the Elements the way you want.

Check out the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: but how to omit -McT4fSeXaMtZG2uitBJ

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flatlist to show list of data

```
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    extraData={selectedId}
  />
```

Here is the reference
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist